# want to print all the rotations of a string

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

i want to rotate the string one place at a time and print all the rotations
Input : S = "abc" 
Output : abc
         bca
         cab

im trying to concatenate the string and then printing it, but the problem is input string can be of size 10^5 so my array would require to be of 10^10 size.
but im unable to declare that size array, so i wanted a to know if there is a better way to do it

```
void printRotatedString(char str[]) 
{ 
    int n = strlen(str); 

    // Concatenate str with itself 
    char temp[2*n + 1]; 
    strcpy(temp, str); 
    strcat(temp, str); 

    // Print all substrings of size n. 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    { 
        for (int j=0; j != n; j++) 
            printf("%c",temp[i + j]); 
        printf("\n"); 
    } 
}
```

i expect it to work even for 10^5 sized strings

Comment: Don't tag it c++.

Comment: @Abhineet Without a language tag, I assume you're looking for pseudocode? (i.e. your question is language agnostic?) I thought the [c] tag was appropriate.

Comment: yes, just the pseudocode will do.

Comment: actually, i tagged it c,c++ but someone suggested to not tag it c++, so i removed

Comment: How did you get 10^10?  If you concatenate two strings of size 10^5, then you have a string of 2*(10^5), or 200000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can come up with another solution using prefix sums. Let's calculate array c where c[i] = the number of letters in our string which are even(or another boolean function) from the beginning. We can calculate it easily if we know `c[i - 1]`, `c[i]` would be `c[i - 1] + 1` if i-th letter is even, `c[i] = c[i - 1]` otherwise.

So let's use the same idea, let's concatenate our string on its own. And then try to check every substring length of our input string. Having prefix sums, we can easily check if the left-hand side has more even elements than the right-hand side.

Here is the solution code:

```
int c[100500];

int isEven(char c) {
    return c % 2 == 0;
}

int solve(char str[]) { 
    int n = strlen(str);

    char temp[2*n + 1]; 
    strcpy(temp, str); 
    strcat(temp, str); 

    for (int i = 0; i < n + n; i++) {
        c[i + 1] = c[i] + isEven(temp[i]);
    }

    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i + n <= n + n; ++i) {
        int l = i, r = i + n - 1;
        int mid = i + n / 2;
        int leftSide = c[mid - 1] - c[l - 1];
        int rightSide = c[r] - c[mid - 1];

        if (leftSide > rightSide) {
            ++counter;
        }
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: can you explain it for string '1235' in brief, just the logic part

Comment: Let's take string '1235', Here we can see that we have only one even number. Let's calculate c array which would be: 0 1 1 1 for '1235' string. For '12351235' it would be: 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2. If we will take every substring of our concatenated string, it would be on of rotations of our original string, isn't it? Having array c, we can find out number of evens in substring for O(1), just substracting from end the beginning.

Comment: Basically, prefix sums are used for finding sum in subarray. f.e. we have an array with elements: `[1, 3, 4, 5]`, prefix sum would be `[1, 4, 8, 13]`. To get sum of inteval [2, 3] we can subtract c[1] from c[3], it means that we have `c[3] = a[1] + a[2] + a[3]`, and  c[1] which is equal to a[1]. `c[3] - c[1] = (a[1] + a[2] + a[3]) - (a[1]) =a[2] + a[3]` which is our sum in interval [2, 3]

Comment: but bro, it will give answer as 6 for '246333'. when the answer should be 3. 246333,463332,324633, plz check once

Comment: sorry, my bad, just change the sign `<` to `>`. I have updated the code.

Comment: and what if the input size is 10^5, will it work 10^10 array

Comment: Nope, it will work in linear time - `O(N)`. We are just looping from 1 to `N + N`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, even without concatenation. But why do you need it? It will be better if you provide an actual problem source.

```
void printRotatedString(char str[]) { 
    int n = strlen(str); 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
            printf("%c", str[(i + j) % n]); 
        printf("\n"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: actually the problem was to find all the rotations of the string where the left half of the string had more number of vowels than the right. eg if the string was "abcd", the expected output would be 2 as abcd and dabc are the two strings. and length of the input string is always even

Comment: It means that the problem is to find out the number of rotations in a numeric string, where the number of even numbers on the first half is greater than on the second?

Comment: yes, can be even numbers for numeric strings or number of vowels for alphabetical strings, anything will do

Comment: @ABHINEET SINGH It is worth to ask about actual problem to avoid [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). (Showing own approach and thoughts is nice)